# Listen to msmq queue

Tags: msmq

Following the is the code I have for listening to messages from Windows form.

I have noticed that when I click on `send` it sends a message to MyQueue but at that time I was hoping the event `mq_ReceiveCompleted(object sender, ReceiveCompletedEventArgs e)` should get called but it is not, in other words I am trying to subscribe to MyQueue from Windows form. Just wondering if I am missing something in the code:

```
public class Form1 : System.Windows.Forms.Form
{
   public System.Messaging.MessageQueue mq;
   public static Int32 j=0;

   public Form1()
   {
       // Required for Windows Form Designer support
       InitializeComponent();

       // Queue Creation
       if(MessageQueue.Exists(@".\Private$\MyQueue"))
         mq = new System.Messaging.MessageQueue(@".\Private$\MyQueue");
       else
         mq = MessageQueue.Create(@".\Private$\MyQueue");

       mq.ReceiveCompleted += new ReceiveCompletedEventHandler(mq_ReceiveCompleted);
       mq.BeginReceive();
   }

   [STAThread]
   static void Main() 
   {
       Application.Run(new Form1());
   }

   private void btnMsg_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
   {
      // SendMessage(Handle, 1, 0, IntPtr.Zero);
      System.Messaging.Message mm = new System.Messaging.Message();
      mm.Body = txtMsg.Text;
      mm.Label = "Msg" + j.ToString();
      j++;
      mq.Send(mm);
   }

   void mq_ReceiveCompleted(object sender, ReceiveCompletedEventArgs e)
   {
       //throw new NotImplementedException();
   }

   private void btnRcv_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
   {
        System.Messaging.Message mes;
        string m;

        try
        {
            mes = mq.Receive(new TimeSpan(0, 0, 3));
            mes.Formatter = new XmlMessageFormatter(new String[] {"System.String,mscorlib"});
            m = mes.Body.ToString();
        }
        catch
        {
            m = "No Message";
        }
        MsgBox.Items.Add(m.ToString());
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to learn to post the **relevant code** - not just your whole code file! Cut down your code to just those methods / lines that are really important to the problem - don't post all the Windows Forms generated code - that doesn't add any value to your post at all.....

Answer (score 2):

See [MSDN's example on how to use the `ReceiveCompletedEventHandler`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.messaging.receivecompletedeventhandler.aspx) .

They have a console app where the `Main()` does the same as your `Form1()`, but your handler doesn't have any code. You've said it doesn't call back into your event delegate, but perhaps check your queue name is correct on the constructor.

Consider **using MSDN's sample code in a new console app** to test your environment first, then go back to your WinForms code with any lessons learned.

```
private static void MyReceiveCompleted(Object source, 
        ReceiveCompletedEventArgs asyncResult)
    {
        MessageQueue mq = (MessageQueue)source;
        Message m = mq.EndReceive(asyncResult.AsyncResult);

        Console.WriteLine("Message: " + (string)m.Body);
        mq.BeginReceive();      
        return; 
    }
```

If you want to inspect the queue and get a message on the click of a button, you can simply move the statement `mq.BeginReceive();` to the `btnRcv_Click()` in place of `.Receive()`;

Comment: Hi Campbell 

here is the modified code:
It only triggers this code when the app starts up not when you click on the button.



<code>
static void mq_ReceiveCompleted(object sender, ReceiveCompletedEventArgs e)
   {
       MessageBox.Show("Sai");
   }
</code>

Please let me know if u have any suggestions.
Thanks